# ! Package babel error, unknown language 'english'...

Tags: babel, languages

I downloaded a programming assignment template from:
http://www.latextemplates.com/template/programming-coding-assignment

I first used pdflatex command to try and compile the tex file and received the error:

```
! Package babel error, unknown language 'english'...
```

I then tried with TexMaker and TexStudio and received the following error. I have read tens of threads on here and the rest of the Internet. I've compiled with different compilers, uninstalled TexMaker/TexStudio and PDFlatex and installed all again.

I've rebooted, updated my system (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), tried compiling on online editors (still getting the same problem).

I've changed 'english' to English, En, EN, en, ENGLISH, I have loaded babel in different ways and used:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
```

Which does nothing. I've also removed the line altogether which does not fix the issue. I've checked my editors encoding was set to UTF-8.

I just want to get on with my university coursework but nothing I try is working at all and would appreciated help getting this fixed.

Comment: `english.ldf` is part of TeX Live package `babel-english`, which should be installed.

Comment: I tried this and ran into an error, researched the error and unwittingly realised I had not installed a required package (which was weird because I spent a good few hours looking up lists of packages, installing etc.) Anyway thank you for helping me reach the answer I required!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about another unidentified problem resolved by the OP that cannot be diagnosed with the information at hand.